Does subsampling improve numerical accuracy in Least Squares problems using Normal Equations?
I have a linear system of equations $A x = b$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $m \approx 10^7$ and $n\approx5$. As discussed in Least Squares: Solving the Normal Equations for Well Conditioned Matrices and references like "Matrix Computations", Golub and Van Loan, when balancing numerical accuracy and speed, QR factorization is generally preferable to forming the normal equations.
However, in my case, I am interested in using the normal equations because the library I'm using (Pytorch with CUDA) is an order of magnitude faster with normal equations compared to QR factorization. Specifically, I am using Pytorch's solve for solving the normal equations and lstsq for using QR factorization.
I think that this difference in performance may be related to Golub and Van Loan's statement (page 268):

the normal equations approach involves about half of the arithmetic when $m\gg n$ and does not require as much storage

However, since I am also concerned about the numerical accuracy of the solution, I was wondering if subsampling the number of $m$ equations (e.g. using $m=10^3$ instead of $10^7$) could lead to better numerical accuracy.
My reasoning is that a diagonal element of the matrix $A^\top A$ used in the normal equations corresponds to the sum of squared elements of a column of $A$. Therefore, since I am using 32-bit floating point precision, these values might lose significant accuracy due to rounding errors.
However, I’m not sure if this reasoning is valid, or if I should instead focus on normalizing the data or using preconditioning to improve accuracy. I would greatly appreciate any insights on this.

How do you plan to choose which equations to keep? At random? Arbitrarily? Do you have a geometric structure in your problem that suggests what to do?

@FedericoPoloni thank you for your feedback and questions. In my problem, I can base the sampling on probabilities tied to "good samples," such as drawing them from a categorical distribution without replacement. Regarding the structure, for the matrix $A$, two of its columns have values in the range $[0, 500]$, which can be normalized to $[0, 1]$ if this is appropriate. Two other columns alternate between 0 and 1: $[0, 1, 0, 1, ...]$ and $[1, 0, 1, 0, ...]$. The remaining columns tipically have values in the range $[-5, 5]$.

@abc I accidentally had put my comment on the wrong forum question. I've removed it.

This recent preprint may be of interest. It uses the $R$ matrix from the QR decomposition of a subsampled $A$ as a preconditioner for the QR decomposition of the full matrix and loses very little accuracy

How badly conditioned is your system of normal equations?  What are you doing with your solutions to the normal equations (e.g. estimating best fit parameters and trying to put confidence intervals on them or trying to build a predictive machine learning model)?

There is some detailed literature on this style of randomized QR, in addition to the preprint @whpowell96 cited. One of the most famous algorithms is one called "Blendenpik", by Avron, Maymounkov and Toledo.

Thank you all for your help and input. @BrianBorchers, in my problem, I can use weights to form a weighted least squares problem. If weights are not used, the condition numbers of $A$ and $A^T A$ are on the order of $\sim10^4$ and $\sim10^8$, respectively. When using a positive definite matrix of weights $W$ to form the normal equations, the condition number of $A^T W A$ is in the range $[10^9, 10^{11}]$. My goal is to estimate the best-fit parameters, which, in this case, can be justified as the maximum likelihood estimate under certain assumptions.

You have a very badly conditioned problem, so look into regularization strategies.

@BrianBorchers thank you for the advice.

@FedericoPoloni I think the preconditioner used in both papers is actually the same so Blendenpik is probably the best choice here. The novelty of the paper I posted seems to be in investigating how sensitive $|A - QR|$ and $|QQ^T-I|$ are to the quality of preconditioning and to errors introduced in the intermediate steps.

You're all trying to fix a downstream problem. Least-squares problems are typically ill-conditioned because the basis is poorly chosen -- the basis vectors are nearly parallel. You cannot fix that later on by preconditioning. You need to tackle the problem at its root, which is choosing a better basis.

The link by @whpowell96 is to A Randomized Preconditioned Cholesky QR Algorithm.

Have you tried running an iterative solver on this such as cgnr/cgls or lsqr in double precision? I believe that this should be fairly fast on the gpu even in double precision.

The statement "since I am also concerned about the numerical accuracy of the solution, I was wondering [whether complicated solution is the way to go]" is just a variation of the kinds of statements to which Donald Knuth replied with "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".
The point is that unless you have specific evidence that numerical accuracy is compromised, you should not replace what you have by a method that is more complicated and introduces its own source of errors. That's because the subsampling will for sure introduce errors, and they may or may not be larger than the round-off issues you are afraid of.
The right approach, then, is first to measure whether you actually have a problem. Compute the condition number of the matrix $A^TA$ and see what that gives you. If the condition number is of order $10^4$, for example, there is no need to do anything about it, and you just gained an afternoon where you have nothing to do and might as well go on a bike ride.

Thank you for your help. I agree that my original question can be seen as premature optimization. In my case, however, the condition numbers are typically higher. Specifically, I can use weights to form a weighted least squares problem. If weights are not used, the condition numbers of $A$ and $A^T A$ are on the order of $\sim10^4$ and $\sim10^8$, respectively. When using a positive definite matrix of weights $W$ to form the normal equations, the condition number of $A^T W A$ is in the range $[10^9, 10^{11}]$.

So the weights make it worse? That seems like the wrong direction. But more constructively, the ill-conditioning in least-squares does not result from the number of data points. It results from a poorly chosen basis. What is your basis, and what are the data points you are trying to fit.
